# Seeing ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle

The following is my query for Oracle SQL Developer:

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENTS (DATE,PARTNER_NAME,ENROLLMENTS)
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM') AS DATE, mrch_bnft_cd, COUNT(*)
    FROM ENROLLMENTS 
    WHERE TS > trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + 5/24 
    AND TS < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') + 5/24
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM'), mrch
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM'), mrch_bnft
```

I get an error

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected error

but the error is not telling me where. Any ideas?

```
DATE = TIMESTAMP(6)
TS = TIMESTAMP(6)  
PARTNER = VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)  
ENROLLMENTS = NUMBER  
MRCH_BNFT= VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)
```

Comment: whats is datatype of DATE, TS fields ?

Comment: Can you specify the data types of `DATE,PARTNER_NAME,ENROLLMENTS` and `TS,MRCH_BNFT_CD`?

Comment: @Andrew i updated the post

Comment: @ThomasStrub i updated the post

Comment: The "into" of 'SELECT _INTO_'  is a PL/SQL language construct, not a SQL syntax.  Unless this is a snippet extracted from a PL/SQL block, you need to get rid of the 'INTO'.  And if it _is_ a snippet extracted from a PL/SQL block, you should have shown it in context of that PL/SQL.

Comment: @EdStevens - this is an `insert into`, not a `select into` ?

Comment: @fsdff - it would be helpful if you did a `describe enrollments` and included that and your actual statement in your question; as `DATE` isn't a legal column name (unless using a quoted identifier, which isn't shown) and you seem to have change other column name inconsistently, this can't be exactly what you are doing. It's possible the issue is in something you've changed, or haven't shown at all.

Comment: @AlexPoole   - In the words of the famous philosopher, Homer Simpson, "DOH!"  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are trying to store a string which represents a date in a timestamp field. 
If you replace:

```
TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM')
```

by

```
TRUNC(TS, 'hh24')
```

at all 4 places it should work.

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENTS (DATE,PARTNER_NAME,ENROLLMENTS)
    SELECT   TRUNC(TS, 'hh24') AS DATE, mrch_bnft_cd, COUNT(*)
    FROM     ENROLLMENTS 
    WHERE    TS > trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + 5/24 
    AND      TS < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') + 5/24
    GROUP BY TRUNC(TS, 'hh24'), mrch
    ORDER BY TRUNC(TS, 'hh24'), mrch_bnft
```

Comment: I need the actual date, this returns the hour 14 which is correct, but I still need the actual date.

Comment: So technically it's working now? But there is a logical error?

Comment: @no its displaying 14 without a date. its the right hour, but the right hour already existed in the first query.

Comment: Where is it displaying 14 without a date?

Comment: in DATE value field @Thomas Strub

Comment: You have written that the data type of the field `date` is timestamp(6) so a select should result a complete timestamp ...

Comment: @fsdff - did you only change it to `to_char(ts, 'hh24')` instead of `trunc(ts, 'hh24')`? Though that only makes sense if your DATE column is actually a string, not the data type you said.